# How to set eclipse project specific validation preferences with m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

When invoking importing maven projects into eclipse from git using "Import Maven Projects" the m2e plugins to seems to generate a new .project and .classpath and some other files even though those files are checked in.

To get around this problem I would like to not check in any eclipse specific files, but there are customizations made to each project file such as custom save actions, or changes to the validation to ignore specific things, or changes to the javascript configuration for a dynamic web project that need to be preserved, so either those files need to checked or those settings need to be generated by m2e.

Any way to use m2e to configure the eclipse project validators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar problem in the past. We solved it by

- don't checkin eclipse specific files (svn ignore, git ignore, ...)
- Use [Workspace Mechanic plugin](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/) to keep eclipse settings the same accross development machines / developers.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer has suggested the solution with eclipse. But if you are flexible with using a different IDE, I suggest using Netbeans with git. I tested both IDEs and finally found out I could save time in different cases using Netbeans! No such problems as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I made [m2e-codestyle-maven-plugin](https://site.trajano.net/m2e-codestyle-maven-plugin/) for another purpose but it should serve what you need as well (in my case I wanted to set the default settings to have all validations turned on from my [coding-standards](https://site.trajano.net/coding-standards/) project.

The key thing you have to do is fork a copy of my [coding-standards](https://site.trajano.net/coding-standards/) project and add/change the appropriate setting in `org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs` namely

```
vals/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xml/global=FF03
```

To disable the validations for XML for example. You can have it activated only on `m2e` by using profiles as shown here

https://github.com/trajano/jee/blob/master/jee-domain-api/pom.xml#L24

```
<profile>
  <id>m2e</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>m2e.version</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.trajano.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>m2e-codestyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>configure</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>net.trajano</groupId>
            <artifactId>coding-standards</artifactId>
            <version>${coding-standards.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```