# m2e / custom project-specific settings

Tags: maven, m2e

When a Maven project is imported by m2e, I need some custom project-specific settings to be automatically included in the .project file (eg. a `<filteredResources>` element).

How and where can I configure such  settings? I found no "place" for it in the pom.xml...

Comment: I found a similar question, but without anser... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006325/how-to-set-eclipse-project-specific-validation-preferences-with-m2e

Comment: Could you explain more what you want to acheive?

Comment: For example: adding a <filteredResources> element to the .project file. This corresponds to the Eclipse settings: Project Properties / Resource / Resource Filters

Comment: I need the exact same feature. I have nested maven modules and I have launch configurations defined in them. But because of the nesting I am seeing the launch configs 3 times (per nesting level). So I wanted to filter those resources... the documentation of m2e is really basic.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this is by using a resource filters extension. The resource filters extension allows plug-ins to define filters that are useful for filtering out file types in the resource navigator view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
      <commonFilter
        description="Hides node_modules folder"
        id="com.pilot.plugins.nodefilter"
        name="node_modules"
        activeByDefault="true">
        <filterExpression>
            <and>
                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="node_modules"/>
                </adapt>
            </and>
        </filterExpression>
    </commonFilter>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
    <viewerContentBinding
          viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
          <includes>
            <contentExtension pattern="com.pilot.plugins.nodefilter"/> 
          </includes>
    </viewerContentBinding>
    </extension>
```

Comment: How is it related to importing Maven projects with m2e? Could you please add an example?